# badly formatted UUID fails in Swift but not in Kotlin

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Swift, if one runs this code, it prints "nil" because the UUID is badly formatted.

```
import Foundation
let id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-badbad"
print(UUID(uuidString: id)) // prints nil
```

However, the same test in Kotlin does not fail:

```
import java.util.UUID

fun main() {
    val id = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-badbad"
    val uuid = UUID.fromString(id) // should fail; badly formatted uuid
                                   // but prints "11111111-1111-1111-1111-000000badbad"
    println(uuid)
}
```

Is the implementation of a UUID different in Kotlin than in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a string in the proper format for a UUID

> UUID(uuidString: "11111111-1111-1111-1111-badbad")

The code you're using, `UUID(uuidString: "11111111-1111-1111-1111-badbad")`, will return nil beacause of bad formmating of UUID also note that UUIDs are only generated for real devices and not for iOS simulators because hardware devices get registered with Apple network to get access to device tokens.

Now about kotlin, this `val uuid = UUID.fromString(id)` function will return the new UUID from above string. You are comparing the two opposite function where one checks the UUID is valid or not and other generating UUID from string.

If you want to check badly formatted uuid then use regex function in kotlin.

Comment: but why does kotlin allow you to create an UUID from a string that is badly formatted? In Swift, it also allows one to create the UUID from the string but it performs some checks and that's why it returns nil: the string fails the checks.

Comment: I think writting one more function to validate the UUID in kotlin is no big deal.